# Width border problem tabularray environment

Tags: tabularray, textwidth, column-width, hline

after I got great help the last time, I´m new to latex and already tried to figure it out for some time... I hope you can help me with my problem.
I try to design a table in a style like that (white lines are a faulty visualization):
[image]

My biggest issue is that the table width extends beyond the text frame and I can´t figure out what I should do. Maybe tabularry is not the perfect environment? I already tried to put it as tblr in a table environment but that didn´t help either.
Otherwise, I still have to figure out how I can "delete" the h and v lines in the 5 last columns as it should be one area without lines for each color. (I would try to work with vlines = {1, 2, 3, 4}{solid} and hlines{1, 2, 3} = {1}{-}{} - but to be honest that seems rather complicated in the end maybe there is a better approach?)
Lastly, I still must set the row height for each row after the header (1+2) with the same height. Quite sure I´ll figure that out but any help/tip is welcome :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewDocumentCommand \TblrAlignCenter { } { \centering }
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {cap},
    lable = {lab},
    presep = {6pt}
    ]{
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {X[2.4,c,m] X[1.2,c,m] X[1.2,c,m]  X[0.4,l,m] X[0.4,l,m] X[0.4,l,m] X[0.4,c,m] X[0.4,c,m]}, width=\linewidth, %columnes are not linewidth
    row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, bg=black, fg=white},
    row{2}  = {font=\bfseries, bg=black, fg=white},
    rowhead = {1} %should actually be 1 and 2 - How can I achieve it?
    }  
\SetCell[r=2]{c}{Multirow Head} & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Multicol Head 1 with multiple lines} & & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Multicol Head 2 with multiple lines} & & & & \\
& R1 & R2 & TX 1 & TX 2 & TX 3 & TX 4 & TX 5 \\
Category name with same height for each row & numbers & numbers & \SetCell[r=3]{c,m,bg=gray9}{TL 1} & \SetCell[r=7]{c,m,bg=gray8}{TL 2} & \SetCell[r=9]{c,m,bg=gray7}{TL 3} & \SetCell[r=10]{c,m,bg=gray6}{TL 4} & \SetCell[r=10]{c,m,bg=gray5}{TL 5} \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & \SetCell[r=4]{c,m,bg=gray8}{} & & & & \\ 
cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & \SetCell[r=2]{c,m,bg=gray7}{} & \SetCell[r=2]{c,m, bg=gray7}{} & & & \\ 
cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
cat name & numbers & numbers & \SetCell[c=3]{c,m,bg=gray6}{} & & & & \\ 
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of how it looks at the moment (red line = text width):

[image]

My implemented packages and settings:

```
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[skip=6pt]{parskip} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\singlespacing
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{vmargin} 
\usepackage[tableposition=top, font=small, labelfont=bf, belowskip=6pt, aboveskip=6pt,  justification=centering]{caption} 
\captionsetup[figure]{belowskip=0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{6pt}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{harveyballs} 
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\NewDocumentCommand \TblrAlignCenter { } { \centering } 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n { e } { TF }
\let \IfTokenListEmpty = \tl_if_empty:eTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \IfTokenListEmpty{\InsertTblrText{entry}}{%
    \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }{%
    \captionof{table}[\InsertTblrText{entry}]{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
  }%
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{%
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionof{table}[]{\InsertTblrText{caption}(Continued)}%
}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{1.5 cm}{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think white lines are expected behaviour. Once you start organising your table like this, you construct a lot of small areas/gaps (thick rules), which you have to handle manually, whether it is a bug or not.

One way to get rid of white lines is to draw rules in the same colour as the background. However, below I merged cells with one extra column.

You can control height of rows by specifying `ht` parameter. You can also change spacing by specifying upper and lower gaps.

I can't figure out how you expect your long table to be broken over pages. It's worth noting, `\\*` might be helpful instead of using standard `\\` in order to indicate which rows should "be moved" together to next page together without page breaks

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}
% \NewDocumentCommand \TblrAlignCenter { } { \centering }


\begin{document}
  \begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {cap},
    label = {lab},
    presep = {6pt}
    ]{
    width=\linewidth,
      width=\columnwidth,
      colspec = {
        X[2.4,1,m, cmd=\raggedright]
        *2{X[1.2,c,m]}
        *5{X[0.4,c,m]}
      },
      % Rules and bars
      hline{1,3,Z} = {1.2pt},
      hline{4-5,7-9,11} = {1-3}{dash=dotted},
      hline{6} = {1-4}{1.2pt}, 
      hline{10} = {1-5}{1.2pt},
      hline{12} = {1-6}{1.2pt},
      vlines, vline{1,Z} = {1.2pt},
      vline{5} = {1-5}{1.2pt},  
      vline{6} = {1-9}{1.2pt},
      vline{7} = {1-11}{1.2pt},
      vline{8} = {1-Z}{1.2pt},
      % Header
      row{1,2}  = {font=\bfseries, ht = 4ex, bg=black, fg=white},   % 
      rowhead = {2},
      %
      cells = {font=\small},
      cell{6}{4} = {r=4,c=2}{gray8},
      cell{10}{4} = {r=2,c=3}{gray7},
      cell{12}{4} = {c=4}{gray6},
    }  
    \SetCell[r=2]{c} Multirow Head
    & \SetCell[c=2]{} {Multicol Head 1 with\\multiple lines} &
    & \SetCell[c=5]{} {Multicol Head 2 with\\multiple lines} & & & & \\
    & R1 & R2 & TX 1 & TX 2 & TX 3 & TX 4 & TX 5 \\
    Category name with same height for each row & numbers & numbers
    & \SetCell[r=3]{gray9} TL 1
    & \SetCell[r=7]{gray8} TL 2
    & \SetCell[r=9]{gray7} TL 3
    & \SetCell[r=10]{gray6} TL 4
    & \SetCell[r=10]{gray5} TL 5 \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\ 
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\ 
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\
    cat name & numbers & numbers & & & & & \\ 
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like your solution is working <3 (At least in my small Test area) I´m gonna try it later or tomorrow and leave a feedback! Big THX!!!

Comment: Works - Thank you